# SQL check a identity card number using LIKE clause

Tags: sql-server

This is my code for creating a table in SQL 2012

```
CREATE TABLE Guest(
id INTEGER,
fname CHAR(10),
lname CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
NIC VARCHAR(10) CHECK(NIC LIKE '[0-9]''[0-9]''[0-9]''[0-9]''[0-9]''[0-9]''[0-9]''[0-9]''[0-9]''V'),
guestaddress VARCHAR(50),
room_no INTEGER CHECK(room_no BETWEEN 300 AND 700),
CONSTRAINT pk_Guest PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT fk_Guest FOREIGN KEY (room_no) REFERENCES Room (room_no)
)
```

And I wanna insert the following record to the table

```
 INSERT INTO Guest VALUES(213,'Alex','King','908249792V','No 20,Park Road,Colombo 06',300)
```

But it `shows an error,with the NIC number`. How can I solve this?

> (NIC national identity card number contains 9 digits and a V like
>   123456789V)

Comment: The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK__Guest__NIC__32E0915F". The conflict occurred in database "dbSeasideHS", table "dbo.Guest", column 'NIC'.
The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use regex instead of like, the query would be more readable(if you know regexes): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html

the regex for your link would be

```
^[0-9]{9}V$
|  |   | ||
|  |   | |The $ specifies it must be right before the end of the string
|  |   | Your V at the end. Case sensitive.
|  |   The number the pattern before must be there.
|  a range pattern for all numbers from 0 to 9
The ^ specifies it must be right after the start of the string.
```

[Sam already answered your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32495299/2828611)

an other aspect could be your `BETWEEN` statement. Is 300 included? Is 700 included? better use `room_no > 299 AND room_no < 700`

Comment: The regular expression is indeed more readable, what universe is this we're in? ;)

Comment: I was more pointing to the fact that regular expressions are generally not readable, full stop. Although I appreciate the tip - regexes are not my strong point!

Answer (score 3):

Your check constraint is checking for apostrophes in between each digit, this should work:

```
CREATE TABLE Guest(
id INTEGER,
fname CHAR(10),
lname CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
NIC VARCHAR(10) CHECK(NIC LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]V'),
guestaddress VARCHAR(50),
room_no INTEGER CHECK(room_no BETWEEN 300 AND 700),
CONSTRAINT pk_Guest PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT fk_Guest FOREIGN KEY (room_no) REFERENCES Room (room_no)
)
```